# Why am I getting the full site layout in all mobile search results?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, mobile-web

With the new search result layout on Stack Overflow, I am not getting the mobile layout from a mobile device (or simply switching a full browser into mobile mode with the link at the bottom).

Though originally noticed on the stock Android 2.3 browser, I see the same behavior with full desktop Chrome & Firefox switched to the mobile site layout.

Instead any actions from mobile which result in a search `search?q=whatever`, such as clicking on tags from user profiles or using the actual search box are leading me to the full search result layout rather than a mobile layout. Seems like this had not previously been the case.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Browser? Platform? OS?

Comment: @Telthien Any - Android browser does it, Desktop Chrome does it, desktop Firefox does it when switched into mobile layout.

Comment: Well, no idea then. I'd change the `bug` tag to a `support` tag, though, if I were you. Fielder's choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The views changed for the new vs. old search and mobile was caught in the cross-fire there.  A build is being deployed in a few minutes with mobile search results that mirror the new ones (with shorter snippets since it's mobile).

This was a quick port that matches the full site in the results list, feedback on how to better improve the UI for mobile search results is of course very welcome.